# Flutter Firestore how to add document with data to all users where a certain collection in my users collection has a document ID of a certain value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how to add document with data to all users where a certain  collection in my users collection has a document ID  with a certain value . This image would describe best on how structure looks and to explain question more clearly .
[image: my users collection]

So what I have been able to do is to get all my user ids and add it in to an array -> userIDs .

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .get()
            .then((snapshots) { 

          final userIDs = [];

          if (snapshots.docs.isEmpty) {
            print('nothing found');
          } else {
            for (var i = 0;
                i < snapshots.docs.length;
                i++) {
              userIDs.add(snapshots.docs[i].id);
            }
          }
```

From there I know I am supposed to perform a WHERE query and add the new document(data) for each userID where the query was true .  As I am still fairly new with Firestore CRUD operations , I do not know on how to this . Some help or guidance would be greatly appreciated . Thanks

**UPDATED** : I added the code as per https://stackoverflow.com/users/5519300/tarik-huber reply into a Streambuilder , but it doesnt seem to retrieve any data . Any idea what issue could be ? Thanks

```
Container(
              height: 500,
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collectionGroup('user_selected_schools')
                    .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: "Liebenberg Primary School")
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else
                    return ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              doc.id,
                            ),
                            //subtitle: Text(doc['content']),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

**UPDATE**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
.where('selected_schools', arrayContainsAny: ['School Name 1', 'School 
Name 2'])
.get()
```

This was the simpler solution I used from answer. I am able to get uid based on selected school from Array . Thank you so much for your help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend not to getAll users and filter later on them. If your app grows in size it would cause you a much higher bill than expected.

Instead try to use a [collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query in firestore to get only those users you want to change. The Flutter SKD also supports [them](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html).

In a combination with the [FieldPath.documentId](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath/documentId.html) for the document ID as it is he school name you can query directly trough all Users to get only those you want.

Your query could look like this:

```js
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collectionGroup('user_selected_schools')
  .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: "School Name")
  .get()
```

Alternatibely you could also save the school names into an array like `selected` schools and query with an [arrayContains](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) query. This ways you could even search for multiple schools selected at once.

This is how that solution would look like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('selected_schools', arrayContainsAny: ['School Name 1', 'School Name 2'])
  .get()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying . I updated my question with the code you provided . I added code into Stream builder but it doesn't seem to return any idea . Any idea what could be missing . Thank you

Comment: Did you create the `index` and adopted the rules according to the documentation instructions https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query ?